# Flutter: package_info.version is always "1.0"

Tags: plugins, flutter, version

I'm trying to get my Flutter app's version using the [package_info](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/package_info) plugin.

```
import 'package:package_info/package_info.dart';
// ...
PackageInfo.fromPlatform().then((pkgInfo) {
  print(pkgInfo.version); // prints "1.0"
});
```

However, in `pubspec.yaml`, I specified `version: 2.0.0`.

**Where does the plugin get the version numer from? How can I change it?**

*Incidentally, `pkgInfo.appName` matches the `name` field in `pubspec.yaml`.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the version from pubspec.yaml, it's the version from Android / iOS platform.
So you should change the version in :

**Android**

`android/app/build.gradle` file

```
    versionCode 5
    versionName "1.0"
```

**iOS**

`ios/Runner/Info.plist` file

```
<key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
```

**UPDATE**

`package_info` is deprecated, use [package_info_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/package_info_plus) instead.

For more information you can check how the native package get the version for each platform:

https://github.com/fluttercommunity/plus_plugins/blob/main/packages/package_info_plus/package_info_plus/lib/package_info_plus.dart#L47

Comment: if its set as....  <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key<string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NAME)</string>.... I'm having the same problem too.

Comment: @Bishoy Hanna
Yeah same as me even the versionName in app/build.grades is flutterVersionName

Comment: Any update on this? and the links provided are not found

Comment: @ShailendraMadda answer updated

Answer (score 0):

This package_info on iOS requires the Xcode build folder to be rebuilt after changes to the version string in pubspec.yaml. Clean the Xcode build folder with: XCode Menu -> Product -> (Holding Option Key) Clean build folder.

Answer (score 0):

Stopping the running app, and start again works